# Single Line FOR /F command FINDSTR error handling unexpected results

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Problem defined is to have a command line that takes the output of nslookup from a FOR /F loop and either sends to the IP Address to a text file or sends a error message.

The simplest iteration I have is:

```
FOR /F "skip=3 usebackq tokens=1*" %a IN (`^"nslookup ADROOT02.adroot.the-server-company.co.za 2^>^&1^"`) DO @echo %a | findstr /C:"Address" >nul 2>&1 && echo found || echo not found
```

However, this only works if an address is found, but no output is received if the findstr fails; i.e. no `|| echo not found` is not activated for some reason.

I am looking for assistance is finding the issue/resolution to have a single command line executable that can define the IP addresses.

Comment: I have edited the command that I get a single IP out from NSLookup but I am not able to update the text log with the failures:
`
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion & FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %a IN (`^"nslookup server-company.co.za 2^>^&1 ^| findstr ^/N ^/C^:^"Address^" 2^>^&1 ^|^| echo FAILED ^"`) DO IF %a GTR 3 SET res2=%b && echo %res2:~10% >> testn.txt & ENDLOCAL
`

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%d IN (google.com ADROOT02.adroot.the-server-company.co.za ) DO (
 NSLOOKUP %%d 2>&1|FIND "Non-existent domain" >nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%d found) ELSE (ECHO %%d NOT found)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Yields

```
google.com found
ADROOT02.adroot.the-server-company.co.za NOT found
```

for me.

Answer (score 0):

With guidance from this forum I was able to put a command together that outputs the IP address from nslookup or error if no IP found:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %a IN (`^"nslookup server-company.co.za 2^>^&1` ^| findstr ^/N ^/C^:^"Address^" 2^>^&1 ^"`) DO IF %a GTR 3 ( SET res2=%b & echo %res2:~10%) ELSE (echo ERROR)
```

Comment: Sorry - you should not rely on this solution.  If tested against `server-company.co.za` it will indeed produce the `ERROR` message, but if tested against `google.com`, the first time, it produces two lines, `ERROR` and `%res2:~10%` and if tested  against `google.com` again in the same `cmd` instance, it produces `ERROR` and `  2404:6800:4015:800::200e` because the previous run has set `res2` into the environment.

Comment: Thanks Magoo, yes. I was about to delete it because of this.